# Getting started with Google Analytics Reporting API for Python

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I am just starting with the Google Analytics Reporting API and used the Hello API tutorial to get started. (https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api)

Unfortunately, I am stuck before I even start. I read it (twice). Created the project, updates the client_secrets.jason file... but when I run the main, it crashes.

```
  File "C:\Python27\New Libraries Downloaded\analytics-v3-python-cmd-line\hello_analytics_api_v3.py", line 173, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\New Libraries Downloaded\analytics-v3-python-cmd-line\hello_analytics_api_v3.py", line 56, in main
    service, flags = sample_tools.init(argv, 'analytics', 'v3', __doc__, __file__, scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly')
NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined
```

I'm new (really really new) to this, so any help (and a more detailed tutorial) would be much appreciated.

Thanks !

EDIT: I have't changed anything from the original code in the tutorial. I'll worry about modifications after I get this running. Thanks !

CODE: hello_analytics_api_v3.py

```
import argparse
import sys

from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient import sample_tools
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError


def main(argv):
  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service, flags = sample_tools.init(argv, 'analytics', 'v3', __doc__, __file__, scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly')

  # Try to make a request to the API. Print the results or handle errors.
  try:
    first_profile_id = get_first_profile_id(service)
    if not first_profile_id:
      print 'Could not find a valid profile for this user.'
    else:
      results = get_top_keywords(service, first_profile_id)
      print_results(results)

  except TypeError, error:
    # Handle errors in constructing a query.
    print ('There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error)

  except HttpError, error:
    # Handle API errors.
    print ('Arg, there was an API error : %s : %s' % (error.resp.status, error._get_reason()))

  except AccessTokenRefreshError:
    # Handle Auth errors.
    print ('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run ','the application to re-authorize')


def get_first_profile_id(service):
  """Traverses Management API to return the first profile id.

  This first queries the Accounts collection to get the first account ID.
  This ID is used to query the Webproperties collection to retrieve the first
  webproperty ID. And both account and webproperty IDs are used to query the
  Profile collection to get the first profile id.

  Args:
    service: The service object built by the Google API Python client library.

  Returns:
    A string with the first profile ID. None if a user does not have any
    accounts, webproperties, or profiles.
  """

  accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

  if accounts.get('items'):
    firstAccountId = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')
    webproperties = service.management().webproperties().list(
        accountId=firstAccountId).execute()

    if webproperties.get('items'):
      firstWebpropertyId = webproperties.get('items')[0].get('id')
      profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
          accountId=firstAccountId,
          webPropertyId=firstWebpropertyId).execute()

      if profiles.get('items'):
        return profiles.get('items')[0].get('id')

  return None


def get_top_keywords(service, profile_id):
  """Executes and returns data from the Core Reporting API.

  This queries the API for the top 25 organic search terms by visits.

  Args:
    service: The service object built by the Google API Python client library.
    profile_id: String The profile ID from which to retrieve analytics data.

  Returns:
    The response returned from the Core Reporting API.
  """

  return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date='2012-01-01',
      end_date='2012-01-15',
      metrics='ga:visits',
      dimensions='ga:source,ga:keyword',
      sort='-ga:visits',
      filters='ga:medium==organic',
      start_index='1',
      max_results='25').execute()


def print_results(results):
  """Prints out the results.

  This prints out the profile name, the column headers, and all the rows of
  data.

  Args:
    results: The response returned from the Core Reporting API.
  """

  print
  print 'Profile Name: %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
  print

  # Print header.
  output = []
  for header in results.get('columnHeaders'):
    output.append('%30s' % header.get('name'))
  print ''.join(output)

  # Print data table.
  if results.get('rows', []):
    for row in results.get('rows'):
      output = []
      for cell in row:
        output.append('%30s' % cell)
      print ''.join(output)

  else:
    print 'No Rows Found'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that caused the error?

Comment: @Noelkd I posted the code

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: that was provided in the commented section of the code ....

Comment: Sample Usage:

  $ python hello_analytics_api_v3.py

Answer (score 1):

according to the error the program doesn't recognize '**file**'. In IPython this error comes up (not 100% sure why) but this error shouldn't come up when running a file. In a file the '**file**' argument will return the full path and the file name.

Try creating a file and running from there or simply paste in a the full path and file name instead.

Also be sure that the client secrets are located in the same folder as your script!